# How to create multiple Conv3DLSTMCell in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to create my model with several conv3d lstm cell layers:
I run the following code:

```
conv1, state1 = conv3d('conv1', _X, [8,112,112,1], [3,3,3], 64)
pool1 = max_pool('pool1', conv1, k=1)
conv2, state2 = conv3d('conv2', pool1, [8, 56, 56, 64], [3, 3, 3], 128)
pool2 = max_pool('pool2', conv2, k=2)
```

The conv3d functions:

```
def conv3d(myname, l_input, shape, kernel, outchan):
  cell = contrib_rnn_cell.Conv3DLSTMCell(input_shape=shape,   output_channels=out$
  hidden = cell.zero_state(array_ops.shape(l_input)[0], dtypes.float32)
  output, state = cell(l_input, hidden)
  print(output.shape)
  return output, state
```

My code runs OK for the conv1 and pool1 but for conv2 layer it shows me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conv3dlstm.py", line 272, in <module>
    run(16)
  File "conv3dlstm.py", line 199, in run
    biases)
  File "/home/user/projects/model_conv3dlstm.py", line 47, in inference_c3d
    conv2, state2 = conv3d('conv2', pool1, [8, 56, 56, 64], [3, 3, 3], 128)
  File "/home/user/projects/model_conv3dlstm.py", line 32, in conv3d
    output, state = cell(l_input, hidden)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 190, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 696, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 2110, in call
    4 * self._output_channels, self._use_bias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 2200, in _conv
    "kernel", filter_size + [total_arg_size_depth, num_features], dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1297, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1093, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 431, in get_variable
    return custom_getter(**custom_getter_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 193, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 408, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 747, in _get_single_variable
    name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))
ValueError: Variable conv_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 2200, in _conv
    "kernel", filter_size + [total_arg_size_depth, num_features], dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 2110, in call
    4 * self._output_channels, self._use_bias)
  File "/home/user/projects/model_conv3dlstm.py", line 32, in conv3d
    output, state = cell(l_input, hidden)
```

I saw the code in run_cell.py at line 2200 which is:

```
kernel = vs.get_variable(
"kernel", filter_size + [total_arg_size_depth, num_features], dtype=dtype)
```

Which is getting variable with fixed name "kernel". If I understand it correctly, it is supposed to be unique. But it means I can't create more of Conv3DLSTMCells than one? Is it a bug or am I using it incorrectly?